# Maintain CLI state using context objects in Python Click

Tags: python, command-line-interface

**What I am trying to do**
I want to be able to have a Python class that holds global configurations that can be used and updated throughout my CLI.  For example, if an attribute of the class is changed by another click command it will be available to the next command that uses the context.

**What I have tried**
I have tried to use a combination of `pass_context` and `pass_obj` to instantiate and pass context between my various commands.

**Minimal example**
Below is a code snippet (not the actual code, but representative of the concept).  The `Dog` class has an attribute `name` that I would like to be able to update using other click commands.  In this case `get` could get the `name` attribute and `set` would update the `name` attribute of the class such that future `get` commands would get the new name.

```
import click

class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name="Jack"):
        self.name = name

@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx):
    ctx.obj = Dog()

@cli.command("set")
@click.argument("name")
@click.pass_context
def set(ctx, name):
    ctx.obj.name = name
    print(f'The dogs name changed to {ctx.obj.name}')

@cli.command("get")
@click.pass_context
def get(ctx):
    print(ctx.obj.name)
```

**Expected behavior**
The `Dog()` class is instantiated when the CLI is first ran and then subsequent commands could update attributes.  For example:

`cli get` would return `Jack` because that is the default value specified in the class.
`cli set Jill` would set the `name` attribute of the `Dog` class to `Jill`.
`cli get` would then return `Jill` since the `name` attribute was updated with the `set` command.

**Actual behavior**
The steps above result in the final `cli get` command returning `Jack` as if the class is being instantiated with each command.

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to work as each run is a separate command and they don't share memory.

Comment: Looks like an opinion.  Consider moving this post into comments.

Comment: Seems to have too less reputation to comment. How do I get more reputation?

Comment: This is a comment!!!  :)  You can make comments... Do not worry.   Also... If you want to know about reputation consider [reading a help post about this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: cannot make comments to the original question. require 50 reputation points. I can make comments here though.

Comment: You are on the track!!!!   You are trying your best to follow the best practices of the community. Keep Pushing!